# How to create an application by using CUBA Studio?

Tags: proxy, configuration, code-generation, wizard, cuba-platform

I'm trying to create a simple project by using the [CUBA platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com). I configure the CUBA Studio as described here: [Installation and Setup](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.8/setup.html)

The screen with settings is shown below:

[image]

[ I'm behind the proxy ]

I need to see examples, but when I click "Samples" I get following error:

> Unable to read the list of samples:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not contain blanks

Next, I need to choose a repository. There are two options. I choose the first:

[image]

Error:

> Repository containing CUBA artifacts not found in:
>   [`https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work`]

In .haulmont\studio\logs\studio.log I see the following:

```
2018-05-10 08:26:06,475 INFO  [com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d] [external_req] Load file content https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work/com/haulmont/cuba/cuba-global/maven-metadata.xml
2018-05-10 08:26:06,604 WARN  [com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae] Unable to read maven-metadata.xml from 'https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work/com/haulmont/cuba/cuba-global/maven-metadata.xml'
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d.c(SourceFile:251)
    at com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d.a(SourceFile:269)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae.a(SourceFile:420)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae.commit(SourceFile:386)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.common.b.buttonClick(SourceFile:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1037)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:119)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:444)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:409)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:361)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.app.aL.service(SourceFile:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I trying to access repository in the browser, I get the access denied error.

When I choose another repository:

[image]

I get the following error:

> Repository containing CUBA artifacts not found in:
>   [`https://dl.bintray.com/cuba-platform/main`]

In .haulmont\studio\logs\studio.log I see the following:

```
2018-05-10 08:30:42,727 INFO  [com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d] [external_req] Load file content https://dl.bintray.com/cuba-platform/main/com/haulmont/cuba/cuba-global/maven-metadata.xml
2018-05-10 08:30:42,957 WARN  [com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae] Unable to read maven-metadata.xml from 'https://dl.bintray.com/cuba-platform/main/com/haulmont/cuba/cuba-global/maven-metadata.xml'
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d.c(SourceFile:251)
    at com.haulmont.studio.backend.m.d.a(SourceFile:269)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae.a(SourceFile:420)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.n.ae.commit(SourceFile:386)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.common.b.buttonClick(SourceFile:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1037)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:119)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:444)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:409)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:361)
    at com.haulmont.studio.ui.app.aL.service(SourceFile:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can access it in browser. The maven-metadata.xml file is downloaded with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.haulmont.cuba</groupId>
  <artifactId>cuba-global</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.0.BETA2</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>6.9.0.BETA2</latest>
    <release>6.9.0.BETA2</release>
    <versions>
      <version>6.4.1</version>
      <version>6.4.2</version>
      <version>6.4.4</version>
      <version>6.4.5</version>
      <version>6.5.0.RC1</version>
      <version>6.5.0</version>
      <version>6.5.1</version>
      <version>6.5.3</version>
      <version>6.5.4</version>
      <version>6.5.5</version>
      <version>6.5.6</version>
      <version>6.5.7</version>
      <version>6.5.8</version>
      <version>6.6.0.RC1</version>
      <version>6.6.0</version>
      <version>6.6.1</version>
      <version>6.6.2</version>
      <version>6.6.3</version>
      <version>6.6.4</version>
      <version>6.6.5</version>
      <version>6.7.0.RC1</version>
      <version>6.7.2</version>
      <version>6.7.3</version>
      <version>6.7.4</version>
      <version>6.7.6</version>
      <version>6.7.7</version>
      <version>6.7.8</version>
      <version>6.7.9</version>
      <version>6.7.10</version>
      <version>6.7.11</version>
      <version>6.7.12</version>
      <version>6.8.0.RC1</version>
      <version>6.8.0</version>
      <version>6.8.1</version>
      <version>6.8.3</version>
      <version>6.8.4</version>
      <version>6.8.5</version>
      <version>6.8.6</version>
      <version>6.8.7</version>
      <version>6.9.0.BETA2</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180425061959</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

An attempt to work in the "Offline" mode is also unsuccessful.

How to create an application by using CUBA Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the Prerequisites section of the [installation manual](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.8/cubaStudio_install.html):

> If you connect to the internet via a proxy server, some Java system properties must be passed to the JVM running Studio and Gradle. These properties are explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html (see properties for HTTP and HTTPS protocols).
>
> It is recommended to set these properties system-wide in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. The Studio launch script passes JAVA_OPTS to the Java executable.

So instead of specifying the properties in the *.bat file, you should provide them as environment variables.